how to trace memory access with QEMU user
I'm running a program named myprog like this:
$ ./qemu-i386-static myprog

I've downloaded the qemu-i386-static program from https://github.com/multiarch/qemu-user-static/releases/tag/v7.2.0-1 , and gave it a chmod +x, and it works.
I want to get a trace of all memory accesses, i.e. all reads and writes by myprog. When I run
$ ./qemu-i386-static --trace "*" myprog

, I see thousands of trace events (one per line), none of them are related to memory accees. Based on the official documentation, I should be running
$ ./qemu-i386-static --trace "memory_region_ops_*" myprog

, and the output should look like this:
719585@1608130130.441188:memory_region_ops_read cpu 0 mr 0x562fdfbb3820 addr 0x3cc value 0x67 size 1
719585@1608130130.441190:memory_region_ops_write cpu 0 mr 0x562fdfbd2f00 addr 0x3d4 value 0x70e size 2

I would be very happy with such output. However, none of it appears.
How do I get memory tracing working with qemu-i386?
I would prefer using a precompiled QEMU, but if needed I can compile from source. If there is a better tool for the job than QEMU user, I'm also open to using that instead. But preferably it should be precompiled and ready to run, e.g. available as a Docker image.
Please note that Linux can't run the program natively, because of the vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536 limitation. But qemu-i386 can run it.
